# How to Iterate through a dataframe to select rows that satisfies a condition including their index in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having a problem to call out the rows and their corresponding index based on the condition defined in my code. I have tried all the examples found here, but none is exactly the same as the problem I have. The dataset looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('Datasets.csv')
print(df)

Posted_Time Label
07/01/2018  13.01
14/01/2018  9.80
21/01/2018  9.08
28/01/2018  8.64
04/02/2018  8.78
11/02/2018  7.27
18/02/2018  7.16
25/02/2018  7.09
04/03/2018  5.85
11/03/2018  8.71
```

`Posted_Time` is the index column, and it is in Datetime Format. I will like to select all rows that exceed a set threshold defined for the `Label` column as follows.

```
df2 = df.ewm(span=4, adjust=False).mean()
mean = df2['Label'].mean().astype(float)
std = df2['Label'].std().astype(float)
thres = std+mean

i = 0
control = True
for record in df2['Label']:
    if record > thres:
        print(i, 'in position!', i)
        control = False
    i += 1
if control == True:
    print('All points are within control limits.')
```

When I run my code, it returns the record position in the dataframe instead of the actual record and the corresponding index (`Posted_Time`). Here is the result that I get.

```
0 in position! 0
1 in position! 1
19 in position! 19
23 in position! 23
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help to correct my iteration code to achieve the desired result below, please?

```
07/01/2018  13.01 in position 0 
14/01/2018  9.80
21/01/2018  9.08
04/02/2018  8.78
11/03/2018  8.71
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
df2['position'] = range(0, len(df2))
for idx, row in df2.iterrows():
    if row['Label'] > thres:
        print('{} in position {} for date: {}'.format(row['Label'], str(row['position']), idx)
```

This will iterate through each row of df2, check if the `Label` value is greater than the threshold, and then print a message if that condition is met. Because you are using `Posted_time` as the index, the value of `Posted_time` for any given row will be held in `idx` during iteration. If `Posted_time` is a datetime, you will have to first convert it to a `str` before it can be printed. Since you don't have a numeric index, we need to add a column to the DataFrame that can effectively tell us the row we are on. This is the purpose of the line `df2['position']=range(0, len(df2))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change your print statement.
you have print(i, 'in position!', i)
I think you need to change the first "i" to "record" if that is what you want to print.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But it does not print the index with it, which is the date. It returns `13.0 in position! 0
9.8 in position! 1`  I also want the date returned. How can I make it return the date as well?

Comment: `print(df[i:i+1], 'in position!', i)`  
That way you get the full row of `df`